# Loading json from unicode string

Tags: python, json

I have a json dumped string dumped in a file.
Here is the file format -

```
{
u'key1':u'abc'
}
```

It's invalid json because its should have double quotes. How do I convert this into valid json?

Comment: You should have dumped this to file using the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: This is __not__ json indeed, this is a Python `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have read this data from your file:

```
s = """
{
    u'key1':u'abc'
}
"""
```

You may be able to convert it to a Python object using `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
import ast
data = ast.literal_eval(s)
# data = {'key1': 'abc'}
```

Note that it might not work with other contents, because it seems you dumped a string (`str()` or `repr()`) representation of a dictionary to a file, instead of JSON. Other, more complex types may not be readable by `ast.literal_eval()`. 
You should use the `json` module instead to produce and write proper JSON to the file.

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

As it seems you are working with Python 2:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html